# How to find betweenness centrality for node in different components

Tags: algorithm, tree, social-networking

How to show that the unnormalized betweenness centrality x of the vertex x, is x = n^2- summation n^2_m? where x lies in different components of tree

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's important to show that you made some effort to find the answer besides just asking SO.

Comment: I am not getting an idea that where to start. like if my graph is tree of n vertices and any particular vertex has degree k and removal of this vertex into k disjoint regions and size of those regions are n1,n2......nk then how can i show normalized betweenness centrality is x = n^2- sumation n^2_m, m varies from 1 to k.